# android intent image how to send it in best way

Tags: android, image, android-intent, temporary-files

At this moment I have activity (lview) with list view which use images downloaded to temporary files from url and `simple activity` (sact) with `imageview`.

on click the value of `textview` in `lview` is picked and send by intent to sact, where it is associated with an object. After object was picked up it is parsed and link from it is extracted. Then this link is used to download image.

```
 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
 SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
 in.putExtra("name", name);
 Log.d("Starting activity ", "Yeah ");
 startActivity(in);
```

In fact both activities use same link and refers to same image in the web. Obviously it is inefficient.

How can i take picture(or unique id)  from image view in lview and then send it to sact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are essentially asking is how to pass images between activities using intents. This is possible but might not be efficient. As far as I know, you can only add [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Seralizeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) objects to an intent.

What you should really consider is having an image-download service that will download the images and either a) cache them on-disk where you can read them from multiple places, b) cache them in-memory at a location accessible to other activities (i.e. static variable) or c) both.

See [this SO question for more information on image caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-caching) or [this one for caching in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536639/best-practice-when-caching-files-in-android).

You can also read [what Android says about caching bitmaps in the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

---